# Output multiple HTML tables to single excel sheet

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, excel

I'm creating two HTML tables in vb.net in a string variable and appending the string text to the innerhtml of an aspx page at runtime. The code to this is as below (This is a sample code):

```
Dim oBuilder as stringbuilder
With oBuilder
 .Append("<html xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"">")
                .Append("<head>")
                .Append("<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html;charset=windows-1252"">")
                .Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]>")
                .Append("<xml>")
                .Append("<x:ExcelWorkbook>")
                .Append("<x:ExcelWorksheets>")
                .Append("<x:ExcelWorksheet>")
                .Append("<x:Name>Summary</x:Name>")
                .Append("<div>")
                .Append("<table style="" border:solid 1px black; "">")
                .Append("<tr>")
                .Append("<td>Column 1</td>")
                .Append("</tr>")
                .Append("</table>")
                .Append("</div>")
                .Append("<div>")
                .Append("<table style="" border:solid 1px black; "">")
                .Append("<tr>")
                .Append("<td>Column 1 - Table 2</td>")
                .Append("</tr>")
                .Append("</table>")
                .Append("</div>")
End With
LogDetails.InnerHtml = oBuilder.ToString
```

The aspx page actually displays the tables fine (one below the other). I tried adding the following lines and use office functionality with XML to name the worksheets. I was able to create and name two worksheets:

```
        .Append("<html xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"">")
        .Append("<head>")
        .Append("<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html;charset=windows-1252"">")
        .Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]>")
        .Append("<xml>")
        .Append("<x:ExcelWorkbook>")
        .Append("<x:ExcelWorksheets>")
        .Append("<x:ExcelWorksheet>")
        .Append("<x:Name>Summary</x:Name>")
        .Append("</x:ExcelWorksheet>")
        .Append("<x:ExcelWorksheet>")
        .Append("<x:Name>Summary no 2</x:Name>")
        .Append("</x:ExcelWorksheet>")
        .Append("</xml>")
        .Append("<![endif]-->")
        .Append("</head>")
        .Append("<body>")
        .Append(oBuilder)
        .Append("</body>")
        .Append("</html>")
```

Post renderring the page, I click a button to export the tables to excel. My button click event does the following:

```
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
Context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Session("ExcelFile").Trim + "")
Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")
Context.Response.Write(LogDetails.InnerHtml)
```

This button gives me a save / open dialog box. When I open the saved excel sheet, I find that it has the two tables one below the other ... I would like the tables to be on seperate worksheets. I don’t want to recreate my entire code because it has years of work … Is there a way that I can put the first HTML table in the "summary" worksheet and the second HTML table into the "summary no 2" worksheet without having to rework the entire code?

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I have been researching on this for over 3 days now ... (Doesn't say much about my research skills)

Regards,
Sunny

Answer (score 0):

I supose you need to render the first table into the first spreadsheet, then change the active worksheet and render the second table.

Comment: I'm not actually renderring the table into the worksheet ... I'm simply outputting the inner html as an excel sheet ... The context.response section of the code does that ... Hence, there is no code in my example to actually tell the program which worksheet it is supposed to use (It simply uses the first one I believe) ... It would help to have some sample code which allows me to specify which worksheet I want the table to be written to .. Although, I found a few links that talk about creating the table values in the XML part and not as html body ...

Comment: Have you tried adding the second worksheet to the code after the first table is pushed and enclosing the code you want inside a worksheet inside <x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheet> tags?

Comment: I guess A lot of pages say that you cannot specify which worksheet to output the HTML table to ... Hence, I will have to rework the entire code and recreate the table within the <ss:Worksheet> tag using cells instead of HTML tags (<td>,<tr>) ... Incase anyone else is facing this issue, Link to do this is: http://forums.asp.net/t/1214938.aspx